# geoip-database-extra serious problem

Tags: apt, package-management

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS(Canonical)
Every time I'm getting the same error message again and again. Even, if I run any command in terminal still getting the same error message. 
So finally I decided to download directly from the web and try to run. But that [Download Page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/geoip-database-extra/download) was also not working.
Even, I am not able to reinstall it.

E: The package geoip-database-extra needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

> ```
>     apt-get install upgrade
>     Reading package lists... Done
>     Building dependency tree 
>     Reading state information... Done
>     E: The package geoip-database-extra needs to be reinstalled, but I 
>     can't find an archive for it.
> ```

OutPut From:- apt-cache policy geoip-database-extra

> ```
>    geoip-database-extra:
>    Installed: 20160408-1
>    Candidate: 20160408-1
>    Version table:
>    *** 20160408-1 100
>          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```

Thanks in advance.

[This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appers again, please report an error to the developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzfXy.png)

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy geoip-database-extra` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I added OutPut in my please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geoip-database-extra` package is located in *universe* section, you should enable it

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

then update package cache and reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall geoip-database-extra
```

Comment: Instead on ` sudo apt-get install geoip-database-extra` i fired  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall geoip-database-extra`.  And it works after enable it Thank for the solution @N0rbert.